# How to mock and test a promise's output value from a service's method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-promise

Prob easiest to test this via live example:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ny8x/797/)

**Question:**
Using mock data, how would I properly test the output of the `PromiseService.getAllData` method so that the output equals `EXPECTED_OUTPUT_DATA`.

```
  [
    {email:'matthew@gmail.com', id: 10},
    {email:'matthew@gmail.com', id: 13}
  ]
```

**MODULE + CTRL/SERVICE:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
myApp.service('PromiseService', PromiseService);

function MainCtrl(PromiseService) {
    console.log(PromiseService.getAllData);
}


function PromiseService($http, $q) {
    const tasks = ['/echo/json', '/echo/json'];

    const uniqueByID_ = a => {
        const map = new Map(a.map(o => [o.status, o]));
        return [...map.values()];
    };

    function getAllData() {
        // this get request is sans a real endpoint.
        return $q.all(tasks.map(req => $http.get(req)))
            .then((a) => console.log(uniqueByID_(a)));
    }

    return {
        getAllData: getAllData()
    }
}
```

**JASMINE TEST:**

```
describe('myApp', function() {
    let MOCK_DATA = [{
        email: 'matthew@gmail.com',
        id: 10
    }, {
        email: 'matthew@gmail.com',
        id: 10
    }, {
        email: 'matthew@gmail.com',
        id: 13
    }];

    let EXPECTED_OUTPUT_DATA = [{
        email: 'matthew@gmail.com',
        id: 10
    }, {
        email: 'matthew@gmail.com',
        id: 13
    }];

    beforeEach(() => {
        module('myApp');
        // how to mock the service to call
    })

    it('should return an array of unique objects by id', () => {
        // expect service.getAllData() to output EXPECTED_OUTPUT_DATA;
        expect().toEqual(EXPECTED_OUTPUT_DATA);
        // output would be:
        //  [
        //    {email:'matthew@gmail.com', id: 10},
        //    {email:'matthew@gmail.com', id: 13}
        //  ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you don't test services in your unit tests, just make sure the promise resolve and reject methods end up doing what you expect them to with the data they're resolving/rejecting. The following code should help you out.

```
var $q, PromiseService;

beforeEach(function () {
  inject(function (_$q_, _PromiseService_) {
    $q = _$q_;
    PromiseService = _PromiseService_;
  });
});

describe('activate method', function () {
  var deferred;

  beforeEach(function () {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn(PromiseService, 'getAllData').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
  });

  it('your case', function () {
    // you can here then do
    // deferred.resolve(yourMockedData);
  });
});
```